# Is this the correct way to copy state in a Redux Reducer?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

In the past I have used `Object.assign()` and done it that way, but recently I was told to use the spread operator. I was wondering if this was the correct way of doing it or if this is mutating the state?

```
import constants from '../constants';

const initialState = {
  all: null
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ITEM_ADDED':
      return { ...state, all: state.all.push(action.data) };
    default:
      return { ...state };
  }
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You did a mutation when you used `Array::push` method :

```
  return { ...state, all: state.all.push(action.data) };
```

And the right way is to use the spread operator also to append object to array instead of push :

```
  return { ...state, all: [...state.all, action.data] };
```

Comment: Could I use concat as well?

Comment: yes!  contact is ok . But , for consistency concerns, you may stick with spread operator whenever it is useful.

Comment: I mean do something like `return { ...state, all: ...state.all.concat(action.data)}`

Comment: I typically use concat since it is faster. https://jsperf.com/es6-add-element-to-create-new-array-concat-vs-spread-op

Comment: no need spread operator  in this case `return { ...state, all: state.all.concat(action.data)}`

Comment: @AbdennourTOUMI and this won't mutate the data at all?

Comment: If your requirement is no mutation , both work. If your requirement is performance also, this is another topic.

Comment: Sure there is no mutation either using contact  or spread operator. You can test that via browser console. `const arr = [1, 2]; arr.contact(3); console.log(arr)`

Comment: "Does concat have better performance? " no idea . But you can test that by console.time and console.timeEnd

Comment: @TaylorAustin  : IF you  open a question "Spread operator vs concat Array performance"  , Please give me the link . I will put a clean answer for you.

Comment: Okay I can't create another post for an hour or so, and I don't think I can link my other post inside my post, I got an account banned for that I believe once. Be on the lookout for it, ill name it exactly that .